# Simple local.storage question on light/dark theme website

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is my simple code

```
function toggleDarkMode() {
  let darkTheme= document.body;
  darkTheme.classList.toggle("darkMode");
}
```

It works well, but I can't for the life of me think of a way to save it in local.storage since it's not true or false, it just modifies the css.

I'd like for it to be saved and stay on the previous choice when it opens up next time.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `window` property `localStorage` to save the `theme` value across browser sessions.

Try the following code:

```
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
if (!theme) localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light') // set the theme; by default 'light'
document.body.classList.add(theme)
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a way you could do it: Cookies.

```
function toggleDarkMode() {
    let darkTheme= document.body;
    darkTheme.classList.toggle("darkMode");
    document.cookie = "theme=dark";
}
```

```
function toggleLightMode() {
    let lightTheme= document.body;
    lightTheme.classList.toggle("lightMode");
    document.cookie = "theme=light";
}
```

and then to check:

```
let theme = document.cookie;
if(theme === 'theme=light'){
    let lightTheme= document.body;
    lightTheme.classList.toggle("lightMode");
} else if {
let darkTheme= document.body;
    darkTheme.classList.toggle("darkMode");
}
```